# Python regular expression for matching beginning filenames with wildcard endings

Tags: python, regex

I have the following expression

```
filingReportURL = re.search(r'Archive[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)', utf8line)
```

Which matches web addresses that begin with Archive but I'm having trouble because I want filenames with an extension but I don't know what that extension is. I.e. there must be a file extension I.e. `jpg` or `.BMP` for every case but it could be `.xyx123`. I've tried adding `[\.\w+]` to the end but I'm always left with the last letter of the extension missing when I do the search. Any ideas on a better and cleaner way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of an input and the output you are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use a simple match like this?
`Archive(.*)/(.*)\.([a-z A-Z 0-9]+)`

The replace match will be `\2.\3` in grep.